# flash external ExternalInterface call in as2

Tags: flash, externalinterface, actionscript-2

I have an external interface call which should retrieve some text from the html that the swf is embedded in.

```
var name:Object = flash.external.ExternalInterface.call(
    "function(){return JSObject.get('Resource', 'name');}");
```

When I put the variable name into a textbox I get the correct text.

when I use geturl with a clickTag, under some circumstances it works (unencoded clickTag url). Sometimes it's undefined (encoded clickTag urls). If I use `name.toString` then it opens `http://www.someurl.com/[type%20Function]` or displays `[type%20Function]` in a textbox.

So I suspect that I'm having encoding issues when passing on the clickTag url. My question is, how do I convert this object to a string or assign the contents of the object to a string variable  to avoid all this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you use `name.toString` you are referring to the function definition, that's why you're getting [type%20Function]. use `name.toString()` instead